# Web Scraping - ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Having an issue with bs4 when reading second value in array within a for loop. Below I will paste the code.

However, when I use line #19, I receive no errors. When I swap it out for the entire array (line #18), It errors out when it attempts to gather the second value. Note that the second value in the array is the same value as line #19.

```
import requests
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

 
SmartLiving_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=Smart%20Living&selectedFacets=Brand%7CSmart%20Living&sortBy="
IEL_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=IEL&selectedFacets=Brand%7CIts%20Exciting%20Lighting&sortBy="
TD_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=two%20dogs&selectedFacets=Brand%7CTwo%20Dogs%20Designs&sortBy="

Headers = "Description, URL, Price \n"

text_file = open("HayneedlePrices.csv", "w")
text_file.write(Headers)
text_file.close()


URL_Array = [SmartLiving_IDS, IEL_IDS, TD_IDS]
#URL_Array = [IEL_IDS]
for URL in URL_Array:
  print("\n" + "Loading New URL:" "\n" + URL + "\n" + "\n")
  
  uClient = uReq(URL)
  page_html = uClient.read()
  uClient.close() 
  soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
  
  Containers = soup.findAll("div", {"product-card__container___1U2Sb"})
  for Container in Containers:

    
    Title             = Container.div.img["alt"]    
    Product_URL       = Container.a["href"]
    
    Price_Container   = Container.findAll("div", {"class":"product-card__productInfo___30YSc body no-underline txt-black"})[0].findAll("span", {"style":"font-size:20px"})

    Price_Dollars     = Price_Container[0].get_text()
    Price_Cents       = Price_Container[1].get_text()


    print("\n" + "#####################################################################################################################################################################################################" + "\n")
    # print("   Container: " + "\n" + str(Container))
    # print("\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n")
    print(" Description: " + str(Title))
    print(" Product URL: " + str(Product_URL))
    print("       Price: " + str(Price_Dollars) + str(Price_Cents))
    print("\n" + "#####################################################################################################################################################################################################" + "\n")
 
    text_file = open("HayneedlePrices.csv", "a")
    text_file.write(str(Title) +  ", " + str(Product_URL) + ", " + str(Price_Dollars) + str(Price_Cents) + "\n")
    text_file.close()

  print("Information gathered and Saved from URL Successfully.")
  print("Looking for Next URL..")
print("No Additional URLs to Gather. Process Completed.")
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What do/don't you understand from _ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'_ ?

Comment: I don't understand why in one instance I am receiving this error then in the next I am not.

Comment: By the way, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. The lack of consistent naming makes the code a bit more difficult to follow.

Comment: _I don't understand why in one instance I am receiving this error then in the next I am not._ Neither do I, can you make the lines and changes more obvious?

Comment: I apologize if the code is a bit messy. This is my first python script to be honest.

Comment: That's fine, no one is born knowing everything ;)

Comment: f you notice I have created a 'URL_Array' on line 19 which contains 'IEL_IDS'. This value contains a URL which will first be connected to to gather bits of information. When this is ran with a single value in the array it runs with no errors. Then once I use line #18 which contains several values it errors out once it attempts to gather the first bit of information on line #28:

Comment: If i run all the values individually there is no error either.

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: That's a nice error message.

Comment: Let me know if I could provide anything to help troubleshoot/

Comment: Well does the error message help?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have created this post in hopes someone would be able to help.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message in your post? It's difficult to read.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wightbread\Contacts\Desktop\Webscrape\HNPrices.py", line 28, in <module>
    Containers = soup.findAll("div", {"product-card__container___1U2Sb"})
  File "C:\Users\Wightbread\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2080, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Something's messed, I don't know it's the parsing itself or the result of the request.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it somehow, I’m working on refactoring the whole thing.

Comment: I think the issue **might** have been caused by the website being unhappy about the frequency/volume of requests your program made.

Comment: Think there should be a wait period between pinging the URLs? I can ping them individually with no error. Issue only arises when you throw all the URLs in same array.

Comment: I switched to using a `Session` from the `Requests` library, which should make a difference, although there might need to be a tiny delay between each request anyway. I’ll try to figure it out through some basic testing.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the full Traceback into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you `import BeautifulSoup as soup` and also define a variable `soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")` with the same name!

I refactored your code a bit, let me know if it works as expected!

```py
import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

smart_living_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=Smart%20Living&selectedFacets=Brand%7CSmart%20Living&sortBy="
IEL_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=IEL&selectedFacets=Brand%7CIts%20Exciting%20Lighting&sortBy="
TD_IDS = "https://www.hayneedle.com/search/index.cfm?categoryID=&page=1&searchQuery=two%20dogs&selectedFacets=Brand%7CTwo%20Dogs%20Designs&sortBy="

site_URLs = [smart_living_IDS, IEL_IDS, TD_IDS]

sess = requests.Session()

prod_data = []

for curr_URL in site_URLs:
    req = sess.get(url=curr_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")

    containers = soup.find_all("div", {"product-card__container___1U2Sb"})
    for curr_container in containers:
        prod_title = curr_container.div.img["alt"]
        prod_URL = curr_container.a["href"]

        price_container = curr_container.find(
            "div",
            {"class": "product-card__productInfo___30YSc body no-underline txt-black"},
        )

        dollars_elem = price_container.find("span", {"class": "main-price-dollars"})
        cents_elem = dollars_elem.find_next("span")

        prod_price = dollars_elem.get_text() + cents_elem.get_text()
        prod_price = float(prod_price[1:])

        prod_data.append((prod_title, prod_URL, prod_price))

CSV_headers = ("title", "URL", "price")

with open("../out/hayneedle_prices.csv", "w", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.writer(file_out)
    writer.writerow(CSV_headers)
    writer.writerows(prod_data)
```

I tested it by repeating the current URL list 10 times, it took longer than I was anticipating. There are certainly improvements to be made, I might rewrite it to use lxml in the next few days, and multiprocessing might also be a good option. It all depends on how you're using this, of course :)

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough for going to the trouble of rewriting this for me. Being new to python, and this being my first script.. it will take me a little bit to digest what you have provided me. Simply copying and pasting it results in an error. I believe I need to install another package. Error is on line #18: "soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")"

Comment: @Wightbread727 What’s the error? Feel free to ask any questions on the code, I stupidly forgot to comment it....

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wightbread\Contacts\Desktop\Webscrape\HNPrices_v2.py", line 18, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
  File "C:\Users\Wightbread\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: @Wightbread727 The issue is exactly what it says right there! I replaced `html.parser` with `lxml` as the parser, since I really like the latter. Try going back to `html.parser`.

Comment: Speaking of lxml, that's actually a potential future change I could make, ditching BeautifulSoup entirely for lxml.

Comment: Works. <3. Seems as if my attempt was close.. yet so far off. Thanks.

Comment: @Wightbread727 Eh, I think you were really close, since AFAICT your code was technically correct. Do you have any further questions about the code? How is this program being used, by the way?

Comment: Let me digest it first. Then I will ask any questions. I greatly appreciate your help on this. I wont be shy, and will ask.

Comment: I have had time to review your code, as well as attempt to reverse engineer it to apply this same logic to other sites. However, I continue to run into issues. I feel like the issues I am experiencing is due to me not understanding when to use Sessions opposed to the URLOpen I was using in my original script. It drives me crazy that when I run these values individually they work, but within an array it crashes on the second value. This time I have a array of SKUs which I am concatenating to gather a request URL to scrape.

Comment: I need to keep track of these particular products, and wanted to look into web scraping. After 3 days of research I was able to put together the script I shared with you as well as a couple others. Your help is allowing me to expand on the knowledge I have gathered and will help guide me to my solution, as well as the whole world of web scraping. Fun stuff!

Comment: @Wightbread727 Would you like me to take a look at the new code? Have you tried adding a small delay, like you had suggested earlier?

Comment: Adding a delay in the original code does not resolve the issue. Errors out still on second value within array.

Comment: @Wightbread727 Is there somewhere else we can chat? The comments on here aren't really made for this.

Comment: @Wightbread727 I might have cracked the code! Try changing either the `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup` or `soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")`.

Comment: Check your linkdin. I'd rather not bloat the comments either. Thanks!

Comment: OMG!!!! It Works!!! lmao.. the little things... removed the "as soup" and changed it to soup = BeautifulSoup. I suppose the original code works, just wrong naming conventions. Thanks AMC!

Comment: @Wightbread727 That was my reaction too, then I was surprised that neither of us had noticed earlier.